# Problem in solving the differential equation $y''=e^yy'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given intial value problem is $y''=e^yy';y(0)=0,y'(0)=4$.

I am facing problem while solving this initial value problem.I thought of integrating both the sides with respect to $x$ but integration was getting complicated for me.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: integrating both sides is the way to go. Why did it get too complicated? Show your steps.

Comment: hint: let $u=y'$

Comment: Your equation may be written $$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{{\rm d}x}}\left( {\frac{{{\rm d}y(x)}}{{{\rm d}x}}} \right) = \frac{{\rm d}}{{{\rm d}x}}{\rm e}^{y(x)} .
$$ Does this help?

Comment: integrating here will give $y'=e^y+c$ and substituting the $y'(0)=4$, will give the value of $c$, i.e. 3 and further intergrating $y'=e^y+3$ will give $y=xe^y+3x+c$ and then using the value $y(0)=0$ will give the value of $c$, am I correct?

Comment: Your second integration is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating both sides:

$$y'= e^y+3\; \implies \frac{3y'e^{-y}}{1 + 3e^{-y}} = 3$$

Integrating both sides:

$$\ln(4) - \ln\left(1+3e^{-y}\right) = 3x\;\implies y = -\ln\left(\frac13\left(4e^{-3x}-1\right)\right)$$

Comment: Can u explain how u got $\frac{3y'e^{-y}}{1 + 3e^{-y}} = 3$? and even further steps I am not getting....

Comment: Divide the LHS by RHS in the first equation and multiply by $3$